# Trying to use OpenFace for face detection

Tags: lua, computer-vision, face-detection, pre-trained-model

I've been searching through the documentation for a while and I can't figure out how to use the pretrained models included with openface.  Basically I have a file with a list of images.  I want to run face detection, and save the output to a file.

I see that the 'models' directory has files like nn4.small2.def.lua, which correspond to various sizes and shapes of pretrained networks.  I haven't used Lua before, would I need to figure out Lua in order to feed images to the networks?